# Is exactly this type of "CDC" covid vaccination card (shown), EXACTLY what is required on entry in to Japan currently as proof of vaccination?

Tags: covid-19, japan, vaccinations

Here's the exact requirement currently (2023) for entering Japan for US folks. A fresh covid test or:

> A COVID-19 vaccination certificate showing that they were fully vaccinated AND received a booster dose. The vaccination certificate must be *issued by a government* or *public health institution* and must include the travelers name, date of birth, and vaccination type and the dates the vaccinations were administered. Travelers who received J and J/Jansen may travel when holding 2 completed doses. All other approved vaccinations must show 3 doses have been received.

Here is literally my colleague traveling with me's vac. record from a typical US pharmacy chain, "CVS"

[image]

It's somewhat ambiguous to me if this is "issued by ..." etc as in the text above.

I'm asking if **anyone here from the US** has actually entered Japan recently, using the "I've had three vaccinations" method, and if, your **document was exactly one of these** pieces of paper ?  (And were you allowed in!!!)

It's quite expensive for my mate to run out and get a RT-PCR, its about 200 bucks.  Hence the question.  TY

United etc are useless, the Timatic is vague and they randomly do or don't know.

Comment: For your privacy I recommend additionally obscuring the CVS store number

Comment: Thanks, that tip may help others, (I have no privacy concerns).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

~99% of Americans have the same vaccination card. Since we haven't heard of stories of Japanese authorities denying entry to vaccinated Americans *en masse*, we can conclude with absolute certainty that the vaccination card above is more than sufficient for entry.

Enjoy your vacation.

Answer (score 16):

Yes, that vaccination card will work for entry into Japan. I'm in Japan now and used that is exactly the type of card I used when entering the country. Have fun in Japan!

Comment: heh perfect thanks !